# What qualifies as a "recreational building"?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I am trying to build a Great Hall in Oxygen Not Included and it requires a "recreational building". Forum posts said that a massage table counts, but I tried that and it did not work. The arcade takes a lot of research. Is there any easier option?

Expressive version.

Answer (score 7):

Build [the Water Cooler](https://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Water_Cooler), it's the easiest to build and maintain recreational building.
From the Gamepedia page:

> The Water Cooler serves as a "Recreational" object needed to create
> the Recreation Room as well as a gathering spot for Duplicants during
> break time.

[image: Water Cooler]

Comment: The water cooler can even be disabled and still count, to eliminate the water drain.

Comment: This comment, if still true, is music to my ears. :)

Answer (score 1):

Arcade Cabinet,
Beach Chair,
Espresso Machine,
Hot Tub,
Juicer,
Jukebot,
Mechanical Surfboard,
Sauna,
Soda Fountain,
Vertical Wind Tunnel And
Water Cooler Count As Recreational Building

Comment: Welcome to the stack, please take the [tour].

Comment: Do You Really Need To Write Like This?